# AWS VPC: What is the best way to BLOCK by IPs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, firewall, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

I'm using `AWS VPC` with `ELB` in-front. As far as i understand, only the `Network Access Control List (ACL)` can do the Inbound **Blocking**, by IPs. But again the problem there is:

- The limitation of the number of Rules inside ACL. Which is only 40 max total.

Again the Security Groups can not do "blocking". So what i do now is, to block the certain IPs by the Apache Virtual Hosts (handle the `x-forwarded-for` ips), which is not the clean approach.

Then what is the proper approach to this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up [Network ACLs rules](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html)

[image]

Unlike security groups, which can only be defined by positive (accept) rules, NACLs can be defined by negative (drop) rules. You can view a [comparison between security group and NACLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Security.html#VPC_Security_Comparison)

Comment: But this was already mentioned in my question. The ACLs have rule limitations. Those are limited to very few amount (the total of 40 maximum). That is not enough in real-world and corporate scale.

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions although none of them rely on existing AWS Services.

1. Deploy a cluster of [NGINX Plus](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-plus-on-amazon-ec2-getting-started/) instances behind your ELBs. Use NGINX's [Real IP module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) to inspect the X-Forwarded-For header. Use pattern matching in your nginx.conf with set variables to block certain public IP addresses. (Below has not been tested.)

   set $accept true;

   if ($http_x_forward_for ~ " ?89.44.27.101$") {
        set $accept false;

   }

   if ($accept = false) {
        return 403; 
   }
2. Route and inspect Internet traffic through your firewall in your existing Data Center (if you have one) and peer it to your EC2 fleet using a VPN or Direct Connect.